# Не работает file_exists на php

Tags: php

file_exists всегда возращает false

```
<?$path = '/images/products/'.$produсt->title.'.jpg'?>
<?if (file_exists($path)){?>
<img src="<?echo $path?>"/>
<?;} else {?>
нет фото
<?;}?>
```

Хотя если просто `<img src="<?echo $path?>"/>` то фото показывается. Т.е. фото физически есть а фот file_exists не отрабатывает. Может быть проблема в том что наименование файлов на русском?

Answer (score 1):

У тебя в переменной `$path` лежит абсолютный путь. По которому файл не доступен.

`file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . $path)`

Comment: вообще вот этот путь показывает /var/www/vhosts/mondial.kz/gips.mondial.kz/application/views/catalog/category/images/products/Кт-1.jpg а уменя фото в /var/www/vhosts/mondial.kz/gips.mondial.kz/images/Кт-1.jpg

Comment: Попробуй тогда просто добавить точку перед $path  в момент проверки `file_exists('.' . $path)`

Comment: Решил проблема так $path = /var/www/vhosts/mondial.kz/gips.mondial.kz/images/products//Кт-1.j‌​pg